# Algorithm to evaluate prefix expression?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, prefix, infix-notation, postfix-notation

I have a prefix expression that only has the 4 binary operators(+,-,*,/) .A straight forward way to evaluate such an expression is to convert it to a postfix expression and then evaluate that expression. But I am looking for an algorithm that does this directly without converting it to any other expression ?

Comment: Are you sure your expression is prefix?  Can you paste a few examples?  Infix expressions are hard to evaluate, and are usually converted to postfix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple recursion:

```
Evaluate(input):
  Read a token from input.
  If the token is a value:
    Return the value of the token
  If the token is a binary operator:
    Let first_argument = Evaluate(input)
    Let second_argument = Evaluate(input)
    Return apply(operator, first_argument, second_argument)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack.  Place your vars and operators and start popping each stack, one for operators and the other for varaiablss (the number of pops depending on arity).

Comment: This is quite a vague answer. Do you have any sources ?

Comment: It's called the pushdown automata model.