# calculate values using entered formula

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my html code:

```
<input id="R1" type="text" value="100">
<input id="R2" type="text" value="200">
<input id="formula" type="text" value="">
<input type="button" id="save" value="save">
```

Here the user enter formula value dynamically like `R1+R2`, `(R1-R2)*100`. I need to calculate final value using the formula.

**Ex:** If user enter value in formula field `R1+R2;` I need the result 300.
How do I calculate the value dynamically?

Comment: I did something like this a long time ago. Try parsing the current infix string to a prefix string using a stack, and then evaluate using the prefix evaluation.

Comment: Search for 'expression evaluator' libraries, like [this one](https://github.com/silentmatt/js-expression-eval/tree/master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this snippet, should work with any combo:

```js
function calExpression() {
   var f = document.getElementById('formula');
   var inps = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
   var expression = f.value.toUpperCase();//' '+f.value.replace(/([-\/\+\(\)])/g,' $1 ')+' ';
   for (var i = 0; i < inps.length; i++) {
      if (inps[i].id && inps[i].type && inps[i].type.toLowerCase() === 'text') {
          expression = expression.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+inps[i].id+'\\b', 'ig'), inps[i].value);
      }
    }
    eval('f.value = '+expression+';');
}
```

```html
<input id="R1" type="text" value="100">
<input id="R2" type="text" value="200">
<input id="formula" type="text" value="">
<input type="button" id="save" value="save" onclick="calcExpression()">
```

Comment: Downvoted this answer first because it uses `eval()`, but converting the expression to uppercase is in fact a simple but clever idea to prevent executing other javascript code.

Comment: Thanks appreciate that. I was upset took care of being dynamic still downvoted... ;)

Comment: Downvoted this answer because you're not able to run real arithmetic expression as `(((R1+R2) - (R1*3)) + 1) / 2` for example .. :/

Comment: @PaulBoutes good catch I added as a RegExp actually it was only getting one. Thanks

Comment: Ok, you get same result as me. So i remove the downvote :)

Comment: Hi joy, thank you for the solution. The calculation part works good. However, When I calculate `R4+R10` the scripts replaces R10 with R1 eliminating 0 in R10. How do I find the exact match?

Comment: @Parthasarathi Actually you need a boundary as well. Added boundary `\bword\b` . Should replace R1 with R1 and R10 with R10 exact match  code updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`. This is the fastest and easiest solution, but you must be careful with it and check with regexp that formula has only R1, R2, (, ) and math operators in it.

Or (better solution) you can find a library to parse expressions, in example http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="button" id="save" value="save" onclick="return calculate()">

<script>
    function calculate() {
        var val1 = document.getElementById('R1').value;
        var val2 = document.getElementById('R2').value;

        var result = +val1 + +val2;
        document.getElementById('formula').value = result;
    }
</script>
```

Because a problem occures with "+" you have to use `+val1 + +val2`

Answer (score -1):

Infix to Prefix Conversion Algorithm:
[Infix to Prefix Conversion](http://scanftree.com/Data_Structure/infix-to-prefix)

Prefix Evaluation Algorithm:
[Prefix Evaluation Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912045/algorithm-to-evaluate-prefix-expression)

Use help from these links.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**.eval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method which allow you to evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string. It's a really powerful method.

Then, you have to parse your formula. With this piece of code, you will be able to add expression like `((R1+R2) - (R1*3)) + 1` for example.

```
  function calculate(){
    var valid = true;

    var regex = /(?:[a-z$_][a-z0-9$_]*)|(?:[;={}\[\]"'!&<>^\\?:])/ig;

    var formula = document.querySelector('#formula').value;

    var R1 = parseInt(document.querySelector('#R1').value);

    var R2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('#R2').value);

    formula = formula.replace(/R1/g, R1).replace(/R2/g,R2);

    formula = formula.replace(regex, function (elm) {
      return Math.hasOwnProperty(elm)
      ? "Math."+elm
      : valid = false;
  });

  if (valid)
    alert(eval(formula));

  }
```

Then add `onlick` event on save button :

```
<input id="R1" type="text" value="100">
<input id="R2" type="text" value="200">
<input id="formula" type="text" value="">
<input type="button" id="save" value="save" onclick="calculate()">
```

Here is the [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/l6nTfEvrUCF3niSYzYwj?p=preview)